# Data on Leaflet JS map not showing up correctly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, leaflet

I am building a Corona Virus tracker in React which displays data on a Choropleth Leaflet Map. I have a data.json file which contains polygon data to draw the borders for this map. The idea is, add COVID data from an API to this data.json file, return this object, and pass it as a prop in the map component. In the map component, the countryLoad function is executed onEach feature in the GeoJSON component in the map. This displays the COVID data with each country colour coded based on the number of COVID cases. The problem is, sometimes the data doesn't load correctly and the map shows up as grey.

I have tried a number of things including adding a timeout which has made it work 80% of the time but it still doesn't work at times.

**World.js file:**

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import "./App.css";
import {
    Card,
    CardContent,
} from "@material-ui/core";

import Table from "./Table";
import { sortData} from "./Helper";
import Map from "./Map";
import { features } from "./data/countries.json";
import "leaflet/dist/leaflet.css";

const World = () => {

    const [countries, setCountries] = useState([]);
    const [mapCountries, setMapCountries] = useState([]);
    const [tableData, setTableData] = useState([]);
    const [casesType, setCasesType] = useState("cases");
    const [mapZoom, setMapZoom] = useState(3);
     
    
    

    const attachCovidData = () => {   //Attach covid data to newFeatures
        const newFeatures = [];

        for (let i = 0; i < features.length; i++) {
            newFeatures.push(features[i]);
        }

        for (let i = 0; i < newFeatures.length; i++) {
            const featureCountry = newFeatures[i];
            featureCountry.cases = 0;
            featureCountry.casesText = "";
            const covidCountry = tableData.find(
                (country) =>
                    country.countryInfo.iso3 === featureCountry.properties.ISO_A3
            );
            if (covidCountry != null) {
                let cases = covidCountry.cases;
                let deaths = covidCountry.deaths;
                featureCountry.cases = cases;
                featureCountry.opacityLevel = 0;
                if (featureCountry.cases < 50000) {
                    featureCountry.opacityLevel = 0.1;
                } else if (featureCountry.cases < 50000) {
                    featureCountry.opacityLevel = 0.2;
                } else if (
                    featureCountry.cases >= 50000 &&
                    featureCountry.cases < 100000
                ) {
                    featureCountry.opacityLevel = 0.3;
                } else if (
                    featureCountry.cases >= 100000 &&
                    featureCountry.cases < 250000
                ) {
                    featureCountry.opacityLevel = 0.4;
                } else if (
                    featureCountry.cases >= 250000 &&
                    featureCountry.cases < 500000
                ) {
                    featureCountry.opacityLevel = 0.5;
                } else if (
                    featureCountry.cases >= 500000 &&
                    featureCountry.cases < 1000000
                ) {
                    featureCountry.opacityLevel = 0.6;
                } else {
                    featureCountry.opacityLevel = 1;
                }
                featureCountry.deaths = deaths;
                featureCountry.casesText = "";
            }
        }
        console.log(newFeatures);
        return newFeatures;
    };



    useEffect(() => {
        const getCountriesData = async () => {
            fetch("https://disease.sh/v3/covid-19/countries")   // Get covid data
                .then((response) => response.json())
                .then((data) => {
                    const countries = data.map((country) => ({
                        name: country.country,
                        value: country.countryInfo.iso2,
                    }));
                    let sortedData = sortData(data);
                    setCountries(countries);

                    setMapCountries(data);
                    setTableData(sortedData);
                });
        };

        getCountriesData();
    }, []);



    return (
        <div className="app">
            <div className="app__left">
                <div className="app__header">
                    <h1>World Overview</h1>
                </div>
                <Map
                    countries={mapCountries}
                    casesType={casesType}
                    center={{ lat: 34.80746, lng: -40.4796 }}
                    zoom={mapZoom}
                    newFeatures={attachCovidData()}
                />
            </div>
            <Card style = {{marginTop: '50px'}} className="app__right">
                <CardContent>
                    <div className="app__information">
                        <h3>Total Cases</h3>
                        <Table countries={tableData} />
                    </div>
                </CardContent>
            </Card>
        </div>
    );
};

export default World;
```

**Map.js file**

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { MapContainer as LeafletMap, TileLayer, GeoJSON } from "react-leaflet";
import "./Map.css";
import "leaflet/dist/leaflet.css";

function Map({ countries, center, zoom, newFeatures }) {
    const [loadedMap, setLoadedMap] = useState(false);
    useEffect(() => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            setLoadedMap(true);
        }, 1000);
    }, []);
    
    const countryLoad= (country, layer) => {
        
            const name = country.properties.ADMIN;
            const confirmedCases = country.cases;
            const confirmedCasesCommas = confirmedCases
                .toString()
                .replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");

            const confirmedDeaths = country.deaths;
            const opacityLevel = country.opacityLevel;
            console.log(confirmedCases);
            layer.options.fillColor = `rgba(0,0,255, ${country.opacityLevel}`;
            layer.bindPopup(`${name} ${confirmedCasesCommas} `);
        
    
    };
    console.log(newFeatures);

    const map = (
        <div className="map">
            <LeafletMap center={center} zoom={zoom}>
                <TileLayer
                    url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
                    attribution='&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
                />
                <GeoJSON
                    data={newFeatures}
                    style={{ weight: 0.7 }}
                    onEachFeature={countryLoad}
                />
            </LeafletMap>
            {console.log(countries)}
        </div>
    );


    
    

    return loadedMap?map:null;
}

export default Map;
```

Comment: What do you mean with "**sometimes the data doesn't load correctly**"

Comment: Sorry, I should clarify. Each country shows up as grey, instead of a shade of purple, with darker shades representing more covid cases. So pretty much, the data being sent as a prop to the map file isn't accurate in some cases

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to be with rendering before getting the actual data from the endpoint.

You will need to move the `const [loadedMap, setLoadedMap] = useState(false);` logic to the `World` component and set the flag to `true` only after the endpoint has returned the data.

So wrap the map rendering (*in `World` component*) with

```
{Boolean(mapCountries.length) && (<Map
    countries = { mapCountries }
    casesType = { casesType }
    center = {{ lat: 34.80746, lng: -40.4796 }}
    zoom = { mapZoom }
    newFeatures = { attachCovidData() }
/>)}
```

and remove the whole `loadedMap` from the `Map` component